# How do you pull the position of something in a file in a loop for long set of data?

Tags: python, text-files

For example:
The y-coordinate of the text file is a value, and the x-coordinate is its position in the file.

10
5
6
4

The first coordinate will be (1,10)

Comment: This is a text file? Does it have newlines? Is it ascii or perhaps utf-8 encoded? Is is large or will it fit in memory?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "pull the position", and the result you are describing is not a "coordinate" in any meaningful sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
c = [10, 5, 6, 4]

for i, n in enumerate(c):
    print(tuple([i+1, n]))

(1, 10)
(2, 5)
(3, 6)
(4, 4)
```